# Retrieving Spark error from Oozie workflow to send in email action

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

If the spark action in my oozie workflow fails, I want to capture the actual exception to be sent out in an email. Right now, I'm using `${wf:errorMessage("spark-node")}` but all that gives me is a generic `application 12345-6789 has failed`. Is there a way to pull the actual exception to be sent in the email?